# What’s the meaning of “flex” in “no flex” and “I might pull up flexing…like aerobics”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I watched a diet video on YouTube, ketogenic diet to be precise, and in the end the YouTuber just said as a conclusion: “No flex”. At 9:55 https://youtu.be/9PQW8QVxS-U?si=3X-ijbhEYoDO-XbP

So I searched a bit and found the other post about Flex, and it apparently means to boast about like showing your muscles.
But that doesn’t feel right in this case.

And also, there’s this song from SAINt JHN called ROSES, guess it’s all remixed but there’s a line saying something with flex:
“I might pull up flexing on these niggas like aerobics.”

I’m sorry for the language. I’m just very confused about the meaning of this word Flex.

Comment: My guess is that “No flex” means you don't have to put on a show of strength after taking the ketogenic diet.

Comment: Hm, I’m not sure it that applies to the video. It shows as something negative. Could you please check the video and offer  a feedback?

Comment: Just before 9:55 he debates "flex or flat" and I guess a detailed study of the topic would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

“No flex” means “No lie” or “No BS” — as in, “I’m not lying” or “I’m not exaggerating.”

> According to the Urban Dictionary, the verb "to flex" essentially has
> one of two meanings. It can mean to show off, to gloat, or to boast,
> which is the most popular definition of the word; however, it can also
> mean to put on a fake front, to fake it, or force it. The second
> definition is usually used in conjunction with the first — as in,
> someone who's gloating about something that they've really got no
> right to gloat about, lying about an accomplishment, or exaggerating
> the truth.
>  <sub>Source: [*Bustle* — "Flex" Doesn't Mean What You
> Think It
> Does](https://www.bustle.com/articles/82669-what-does-flex-mean-in-slang-or-why-both-no-flex-zones-and-flex-friendly-zones)</sub>

Comment: I’m no sure this fits the video. I found it and included it.

Answer (score 0):

[Flex](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flex) can mean

> to show that you are very proud or happy about something you have done or something you own, usually in a way that annoys people